# angularJS Unit Testing

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

Using VISUAL STUDIO 2013 and having a asp.net-mvc app with angularjs. 
In order to test angularJS do we need RESHARPER AND JASMINE TEST package?

Or we can **test** just using JASMINETEST APP + KARMA ONLY?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Karma, but you could take a look at Chutzpah - it's a VS add-on that allows the unit test framework to recognize and run Jasmine tests in a headless browser. You can install it from nuget.

Shawn Wildermuth has a Pluralsight course that includes a section on testing JS and Angular code in an MVC app with Jasmine and Chutzpah. The course is called 'Building a Site with Bootstrap, AngularJS, ASP.NET, EF and Azure' (catchy title).

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you only need jasmine to test the apps.  You can create an HTML page with references to the files you have and want to test and then hit that HTML page.  You'll run the tests.

Karma is a test runner so it does the "opening browser" portion for you among other things.